# Counting duplicate objects in array of Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to parse the sub-objects of a Javascript object to count the number of sub-objects that are the same and return a new JSON object with those counts. That's probably not very clear, so here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLTFC/).

Given the `crsListData` in the fiddle, I'd like to return this:

```
objToReturn = [
            {
                key: "Consigned",
                values:
                    [
                        { mapKey: 2007 (4), mapVal: [["Ford F-150 (3)"], ["Honda Civic (1)"]] },
                        { mapKey: 2011 (1), mapVal: "Toyota Camry (1)" },
                        { mapKey: 2005 (1), mapVal: "Dodge RAM (1)" }
                    ]
            },
            {
                key: "Run",
                values:
                    [
                        { mapKey: 2007 (2), mapVal: "Ford F-150 (2)" },
                        { mapKey: 2011 (1), mapVal: "Toyota Camry (1)" }
                    ]
            },
            {
                key: "Sold",
                values:
                    [
                        { mapKey: 2007 (1), mapVal: "Ford F-150 (1)" },
                        { mapKey: 2011 (1), mapVal: "Toyota Camry (1)" }
                    ]
            }
        ];
```

If you'll notice in the fiddle, I've commented on a part about the mapKey and mapValue. They will be determined by function parameters obtained from a select option to order by Model (count)/Year (count), or Year (count)/Model (count).

My end goal here is to generate an HTML tree that essentially looks like this:

1. Consigned (# of consigned)

   - 2007 (total count of 2007 models)

     - Model 1 (count)
     - Model 2 (count)
   - 2011 (total count of 2007 models)
2. Run (# of run)

   - 2007 (total count of 2007 models)

     - Model 1 (count)
     - Model 2 (count)
   - 2011 (total count of 2007 models)
3. Sold (same as above)

The order of the years should be based on the total count of models for that year (highest # first). Similarly, the order of the models under the years should be ordered by highest count.

Alternatively, if the user selects Model/Year for the grouping, I'd like to generate:

1. Consigned (# of consigned)

   - Model1 (total count of this model for all years)

     - Year 1 (count of models for this year)
     - Year 2 (count of models for this year)
   - Model2 (total count of this model for all years)
2. Run (# of run)

   - Model1 (total count of this model for all years)

     - Year 1 (count of models for this year)
     - Year 2 (count of models for this year)
   - Model2 (total count of this model for all years)
3. Sold (same as above)

The ordering of this would be based on counts as well. Let me know if you need any clarification! Thanks!

Comment: que the script kiddie avalanche of "that's not json" 5, 4, 3

Comment: @WillWeld that's not json.  JSON is a *notation*.  What you have there is a *JavaScript Object*.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Oops...changed the title - better? Edit: I'm terrible with semantics. Is objToReturn a JSON array of Javascript objects? Or is it a Javascript object with sub-objects?

Comment: @WillWeld - It's an array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of what you want to do is simple. You want to group data by some property. What makes it seem complicated is that you want to do it at several levels.

First you have 3 set of data "Consigned", "Run", "Sold". Solve it for one and you solve it for all.

First you have the cars grouped by model. Within the model you have the cars grouped by year. Again the core of it though is that you want to group data by some property.

You can use a function like this to do that:

```
var cars = [
            { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
            { year: 2011, model: "Toyota Camry" },
            { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
            { year: 2007, model: "Ford F-150" },
            { year: 2005, model: "Dodge RAM" }
        ];

function groupBy(propertyName, array) {
    var groupedElements = {};

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var element = array[i];
        var value = element[propertyName];

        var group = groupedElements[value];
        if(group == undefined) {
            group = [element];
            groupedElements[value] = group;
        } else {
            group.push(element);
        }
    }

    return groupedElements;
}

var result = groupBy("year", cars)
```

The output will be this:

```
{
    "2005": [
        {
            "year": 2005,
            "model": "Dodge RAM"
        }
    ],
    "2007": [
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        },
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        },
        {
            "year": 2007,
            "model": "Ford F-150"
        }
    ],
    "2011": [
        {
            "year": 2011,
            "model": "Toyota Camry"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can play with it in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/jCt2k/

You can accomplish what you want to doing this grouping at each level. First group by year. Then go through each of the generate groups and group by year. Your count will be the `length` of the values array.

Comment: You did it friend (y)