# How to find duplicates, count elements in array using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a form in HTML. In this form, I can build catalog preferences.
When I'm done with that I can click on save button and build a next one. The result is saving in an array.

When I have more than one saved catalog(sku=stock keeping unit) in my array it's possible that there are some duplicates. How can I remove the duplicates and count them (The quantity should stay even if there is a duplicate)?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwt7nj8g/1/)

```
Array(Array(
      0:5016s18gercol, //sku(stock keeping unit)
      1: 100,          //quantity
      2: 5017ext10002, //extra sku for extra costs(cataloge in color)
      3: 1
      ),
     Array(
      0:5016s43gerbw, //sku
      1: 100,         //quantity
      2: 5017ext10001,//extra sku for extra costs(catalog own cover)
      3: 1            //quanitity extra costs
     ),
     Array(
      0: "5016s43gercol" //sku 
      1: "400"           //quantity
      2:"5017ext10001"   //extra sku (own cover)
      3:"1"              //quantity sku
      4:"5017ext10002"   //extra sku (in color)
      5:"1"              //quantity sku
     )
 )
```

This is what i get. It should look like this:

```
array(5016s18gercol,
500,
5017ext10002,
2,
5017ext10001,
2)
```

Every sku is unique so i cant have two same sku's. I have to count them if there are more than one.

Comment: You're aware that besides arrays, JavaScript also has objects, right?

Comment: okey so how can i do this with objects ?

Comment: possible duplicates of:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489705/4248328

Comment: its helpful but not a possible duplicate. i have to eliminate and count duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
var values = [
    { name: 'someName1' },
    { name: 'someName2' },
    { name: 'someName4' },
    { name: 'someName2' }
];

var valueArr = values.map(function(item){ return item.name });
var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
    return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
});
console.log(isDuplicate);
```